# Has Many relationship how to

Tags: cakephp

I have this model and controller and it returns fine if it is a hasOne relationship but now DishCategory hasMany dishes. When I change the code below to hasMany it gives me an error saying Dish.id is not a known column while if it is a hasOne it works fine. How can I make it so that it returns all the Dish.id's that have id=1? (still using the join).

```
  class DishCategory extends AppModel{

               public $hasOne = array(
                'Dish' => array(
                    'className' => 'Dish',
                    'foreignKey' => 'dish_category_id'
                )
            );

     }

class DishCategoriesController extends AppController {

 function get_categories($id)
      { 
        // find category with a dish of $id
        $this->set('dishes', $this->DishCategory->find('all', array(
          'conditions' => array(
            'Dish.id' => $id
          )
        )));

        // set master layout
        $this->layout = 'master_layout';
      }     
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasOne` relations can be joined into the primary SQL query. `hasMany` relations cannot and need to be queried in a separate query. The `conditions` you specify for the query only apply to the primary query, all separate relational queries are build just based on the `id`s retrieved in the primary query. Set debug to 2 and have a good look at the query log to see what I mean.

To find the category of a dish, fetch the dish and look at its related category record:

```
$dish = $this->Dish->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Dish.id' => $id)));
echo $dish['DishCategory']['name'];
```

Since I take it that a dish `belongsTo` one category, your query *"find all categories which have a dish with id x"* makes little sense; there should only be one anyway.

Comment: Not really, My dish category is 'Appetizer' with Id one, and in the Dishes table I have 6 records with category_id = 1, so one category has many dishes. - by the way this what i would like to know.. how can I retrieve my one category and all the dishes related to it..

Comment: You know what let me reformulate the question, can I create a separate controller and model to retrieve the dishes but use it in one view? so I can use the both data?, if so.. how would I pass the id in the url and how do I call two actions for one view?

Comment: If you want to find all dishes in a category, your condition must relate to the category id, not the dish id. So either `$this->Dish->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Dish.dish_category_id' => $id)))` or `$this->DishCategory->find('first', array('conditions' => array('DishCategory.id' => $id)))` and then use `$dishCategory['Dish']`.